# How to get rid of multiple duplicate menus in Firefox bookmarks library?

Tags: firefox, menu, bookmarks

In my Firefox bookmarks in Ubuntu 14.04, every single folder in my library is duplicated, and I can't delete these duplicates. The duplicates are also linked, so if I change one, it changes the other.

This is a little hard to explain, so I have also posted [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3pTu.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Can't you just right click and delete?

Comment: Nope. It won't let me delete them. Plus I think they're linked to each other.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by a corrupted places.sqlite or by importing a HTML backup that created those extra, normal, folders instead of placing the bookmarks in the existing root bookmark folders that have the special icons.

Check this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/950830) for more info.

Also take a look on this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/places-maintenance/): it will run some maintenance tasks on your browser and reindex the sqlite file.

This link ("kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite") explains what is sqlite and what it has to do with Firefox. If you're interested.

Comment: I had to reinstall due to an unrelated issue, and this issue is not present with the new Firefox Sync.

Comment: Actually, the problem is back. Damn it.